# Sine fitting using scipy is not returning good fit

Tags: python, function, scipy, trigonometry, wave

trying to fit some sine wave to data i collected. But Amplitude and Frequency are way off. Any suggestions?

```
x=[0,1,3,4,5,6,7,11,12,13,14,15,16,18,20,21,22,24,26,28,29,30,31,32,35,37,38,40,41,42,43,44,45,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,57,58,60,61,62,63,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,73,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,112,114,115,116,117,120,122,123,124,125,128,129,130,131,132,136,137,138,139,140,143,145,147,148,150,151,153,154,155,156,160,163,164,165,167,168,169,171,172,173,175,176,177,178,179,180,181,182,183,184,185,186,187,188,189,190,191,192,193,194,195,196,197,199,201,202,203,204,205,207,209,210,215,217,218,223,224,225,226,228,230,231,232,233,234,235,236,237,238,239,240,241,242,243,244,245,246,247,248,249,250,251,252,254,255,256,257,258,259,260,261,262,263,264,265,266,267,269,270,271,272,273,274,275,276,279,280,281,282,286,287,288,292,294,295,296,298,301,302,303,310,311,312,313,315,316,317,318,319,320,321,323,324,325,326,328,329,330,331,332,333,334,335,336,337,338,339,340,341,342,343,344,345,348,349,350,351,352,354,356,357,358,359,362,363,365,366,367,371,372,373,374,375,377,378,379,380,381,382,383,384,385,386,387,388,389,390,391,392,393,394,395,396,397,398,399,400,401,402,404,405,406,407,408,411,412,413,417,418,419,420,421,422,428,429,431,435,436,437,443,444,445,446,450,451,452,453,454,455,456,459,460,461,462,464,465,466,467,468,469,470,471,472,473,474,475,476,478,479,480,481,482,483,484,485,486,487,488,489,490,491,492,493,495,496,497,498,499,500,501,505,506,507,512,513,514,515,516,517,519,521,522,523,524,525,526,528,529,530,531,532,533,535,537,538,539,543,544,545,546,547,548,549,550,551,552,553,554,555,556,557,559,560,561,562,563,564,566,567,568,569,570,571,572,573,574,575,577,578,579,584,585,586,588,591,592,593,594,596,598,600,601,603,604,605,606,607,608,609,610,611,612,613,614,615,616,617,618,620,621,622,623,624,625,626,627,628,629,630,631,632,633,634,635,636,637,638,639,640,642,643,644,646,647,648,650,652,653,654,655,656,660,661,662,663,665,666,667,668,669,670,671,672,673,676,677,678,679,680,681,682,684,685,687,688,690,691,692,693,694,695,696,697,698,701,702,703,704,707,708,709,710,712,713,714,715,717,718,719,721,722,723  ]
y=[53.66666667,53.5,51,53.66666667,54.33333333,55.5,57,59,56.5,57.33333333,56,56,57,58,58.66666667,59.5,57,59,58,61.5,60,61,62.5,67,60.66666667,62.5,64.33333333,64,64,65,65,65.66666667,68,70.5,67,67.5,71.5,65,70.5,73.33333333,72,67,76,73.5,72.83333333,75,73,74,73,71,70.5,73.16666667,70,75,69,71,68.33333333,68.5,66.75,62,63.5,63,62.5,61,53.5,61.25,55,57.5,62,54.75,56.5,52.33333333,52.33333333,49,47.66666667,47.5,45,44,42.5,41,37,37.2,34.5,33.4,33.2,34,26,28.6,25,25.5,27,22.66666667,21.66666667,21.5,22.5,22,19.8,19.66666667,20,20,17,26,22.6,19,28,26.33333333,24.25,27,28.5,30,24,33,31,41,38,22,31.66666667,30,39,26,33.5,40,40.5,38,44,47,48,43,42.5,44,43,51.5,48,49.66666667,51.5,47,56,50,50,58,51,58,58.5,57.33333333,57.5,64,57,59,56.5,65.5,60,63.66666667,62,62,65.33333333,66.5,65,66,65,68,65.5,65.83333333,60,65.5,70,68,64,65.42857143,62,68,63.25,62,63.33333333,60.4,59,52.5,52.6,55.16666667,50,51,45.33333333,48.33333333,39.4,38.25,34.33333333,43.25,31.33333333,29.5,29.5,29,27,26,27,25.5,24.5,23,22,22.5,19.5,20,20,18,18.5,17,16,16,15,14,14.5,13,12.5,11.5,11,11,11,10.5,10.5,9,9,10,10,10.5,9,10,10,11,11,11,10,10.66666667,12,12,12.5,13,13,14,14,14.5,16,16,18,16.5,20.5,21.5,21,25,28,22,29,29,28.66666667,36,42,36.75,43.5,48,44.75,50.66666667,53.75,51,57.33333333,58.5,58.66666667,60,60.25,61.75,60,58.5,63,61,60.33333333,62,63,63,60,61.5,62.33333333,62.66666667,61,63.5,61,61.66666667,62,59,60,57.5,56,57,58.5,52.5,50.5,47.5,49.66666667,49.66666667,54.66666667,45.66666667,41,44,33.16666667,49,45,29.5,39.5,29,20.5,23.5,23,19,18.66666667,17,16.75,15.5,15,16,17,13.5,12.2,12,14,13,11,11.5,11.5,11,11.5,11,11.5,11.5,12,13,13,13,13,13.5,14,14,14,15,17,15,16,16,17,18,17,18,18.5,19.5,20.5,20,21.5,20,22,22,23,23,25,26,28,29,36.25,31,37.75,41.33333333,43.6,37.5,46.5,38,47.33333333,46.75,47,50.5,48.5,58,50.5,48.75,54.33333333,56,49,55.5,60,56.5,56,60,56.5,52.75,54,56,57,56,52.66666667,52,52.66666667,53,47.66666667,44,48,50.5,45,46.66666667,48,44.66666667,42.33333333,46.5,43,36.75,41,28,35,36.5,36,37.33333333,24,30.5,29,29.33333333,32.5,20,25.5,27.5,18,33,25.75,26,19.5,16,15.5,18,13,21,12,12.25,11,5,9,10,7.5,5,7.5,4,4.5,5.666666667,3.5,6.5,5,7,7.333333333,7,9,7.5,9,9.5,11,9,10,12,11.5,12.5,13,14,13.5,13,14,15,15,16,16.5,17.5,19.66666667,19.33333333,20.5,23.66666667,25.5,28.75,31,32.66666667,33.66666667,29,32.33333333,37.6,31,39.5,49,44.14285714,41,42.16666667,45,47.66666667,50.2,52.66666667,52,50,54,53.33333333,54.66666667,54.5,54,56,54,53.5,53,53,52,51.5,51.5,52,48,53,48,50,49.5,48.5,46,45,47,49,48,44,42,42,43,43,42.5,41.5,39.5,46,36,37.5,39,39,38,43,40,38,32.5,34,35.33333333,35,35,30.5,30,31.33333333,33,26,30,27,24,30,28,25,29,25.33333333]

from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from numpy import sin
def fitting(x, a, b, c):
    return a * sin(b*x + c)
constants = curve_fit(fitting, x, y)
a_fit= constants[0][0]
b_fit= constants[0][1]
c_fit = constants[0][2]
fit_y=[]
for i in x:
    fit_y.append(fitting(i, a_fit, b_fit, c_fit))
plt.plot(x,fit_y, '--', color='red')
plt.scatter(x,y)
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add an offset to your fitting function, as your data clearly has an offset around 40.
And then you need a proper initial estimate parameter *p0* so that the fit converges to the ideal solution. This will do the job :

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from numpy import sin 

def fitting(x, a,b,c,d):
    return a * sin(b*x + c) + d

p0 = [ (np.max(y)-np.min(y))/2, 6/150, 0, np.mean(y)]
constants = curve_fit(fitting, x, y , p0=p0 )


guess_y = [ fitting(i, *p0) for i in x]
fit_y = [ fitting(i, *constants[0]) for i in x]

plt.plot(x,guess_y, '--', color='green',label='guess') 
plt.plot(x,fit_y, '--', color='red',label='fit')
plt.scatter(x,y,label='data') plt.legend()
plt.legend()
```

If you feel like it, you could even add a linear offset (a*x+b)

*Note : thanks for the edit jonsca*

Answer (score 2):

I would add this as a comment, but I can't. Fundamentally, `a * sin(b*x + c)` isn't going to fit well to your data, you don't have an average value of zero so you'd have to try `a*sin(b*x +c) + d`, but even then I don't think you'll get a great fit. You could try:

1. Give it some initial values to work with using the p0 input argument https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html . It never hurts to help the minimizer out..
2. Try a different function, what you have here looks like a sin wave, with offset 'a0' and maybe a decaying amplitude.

But you really need to just look at your data before trying to force a function to fit to it.